# Where is $node->rendered being set?

Tags: nodes

Given the following code:

```
function hook_search_execute($keys = NULL, $conditions = NULL) {
  // Build matching conditions
  $query = db_select('search_index', 'i', array('target' => 'slave'))->extend('SearchQuery')->extend('PagerDefault');
  $query->join('node', 'n', 'n.nid = i.sid');
  $query
    ->condition('n.status', 1)
    ->addTag('node_access')
    ->searchExpression($keys, 'node');

  // Insert special keywords.
  $query->setOption('type', 'n.type');
  $query->setOption('language', 'n.language');
  if ($query->setOption('term', 'ti.tid')) {
    $query->join('taxonomy_index', 'ti', 'n.nid = ti.nid');
  }
  // Only continue if the first pass query matches.
  if (!$query->executeFirstPass()) {
    return array();
  }

  // Add the ranking expressions.
  _node_rankings($query);

  // Load results.
  $find = $query
    ->limit(10)
    ->execute();
  $results = array();
  foreach ($find as $item) {
    // Build the node body.
    $node = node_load($item->sid);
    node_build_content($node, 'search_result');
    $node->body = drupal_render($node->content);

    // Fetch comments for snippet.
    $node->rendered .= ' ' . module_invoke('comment', 'node_update_index', $node);
    // Fetch terms for snippet.
    $node->rendered .= ' ' . module_invoke('taxonomy', 'node_update_index', $node);

    $extra = module_invoke_all('node_search_result', $node);

    $results[] = array(
      'link' => url('node/' . $item->sid, array('absolute' => TRUE)),
      'type' => check_plain(node_type_get_name($node)),
      'title' => $node->title,
      'user' => theme('username', array('account' => $node)),
      'date' => $node->changed,
      'node' => $node,
      'extra' => $extra,
      'score' => $item->calculated_score,
      'snippet' => search_excerpt($keys, $node->body),
    );
  }
  return $results;
}
```

Where does `$node->rendered` come from? Where is it defined and what does it contain?

Answer (score 1):

`$node->rendered` is set in [`node_search_execute()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_search_execute/7):

```
$build = node_view($node, 'search_result');
unset($build['#theme']);
$node->rendered = drupal_render($build);
```

It contains the rendered node display for the search_result view mode.

Comment: thanks for the answer , but from where the word "rendered" came  from.

Comment: You mean in terms of English? It's the past participle of the word _[render](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Render)_

Comment: no , i mean  " $node->rendered" where rendered must be  the properties of node  object . so  what  is  class name from  where it   drive  from.

Comment: Oh ok, `$node` is a `stdClass` object, it's not typed (it will be in Drupal 8)

Comment: oh  thnkx  thats what i was looking  for . is $node defined as object of stdClass anywhere ??

Comment: The object is actually instantiated by the database API...in [`NodeController::load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/DrupalDefaultEntityController%3A%3Aload/7) the entities are loaded from the database using the `fetchAllAssoc()` method. That method creates a `stdClass` for each row returned by the query, and those objects are the nodes that get passed around memory